# Want to open user-generated URL in new tab of Safari

Tags: javascript, url, safari, applescript

I've just started using applescript, i want to make to make an application that prompts the user to enter a URL. After this, the application opens the given URL in a new tab of Safari. This is what i have, but it's not working.

```
    tell me
        activate
        set s to display dialog "Which website do you want to open?" default answer "https://www."
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Safari" to activate
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "New Tab" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell

    tell application "Safari"
        set URL of document 1 to "text returned of s"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

By enclosing "text returned of s" in quotes, you have made it a literal string, instead of the record property you are wanting to use - removing the quotes will make it work.  You don't have to script the user interface to make a tab though, that command is in Safari's scripting dictionary, for example:

```
tell me to activate
set s to text returned of (display dialog "Which website do you want to open?" default answer "https://www.")
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab)
        set URL of current tab to s
    end tell
end tell
```